# C# XML Serialization XmlNodes with Same Name

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am currently working on a C# Tool that has to serialize and deserialize objects which contain nested objects with the same name but different content/attributes.It's basically a generic list with n levels where nodes with the same name have different content depending on the parent node. Now I have the issue that I can't do that with the default XML-Serializer because it does not know which class to pick if there are different classes with the same name.

Example Xml :

```
<assembly>
   <content>
      <add x="1" y="2"></add>
      <xml path="C:/abc.xml">
         <add z="1">
            <dummyNode>Content to Insert</dummyNode>
         </add>
      </xml>
   </content>
</assembly>
```

Classes :

AssemblyClass.cs

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("assembly")]
public class AssemblyClass
{
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("content")]
       public ContentClass Content
}
```

ContentClass.cs

```
public class Content
{
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement]
       public List<ContentEntry> Entries;
}
```

ContentEntry.cs

```
public class ContentEntry
{
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement]
       public List<ContentEntry> SubEntries;
}
```

generic/add.cs

```
public class add : ContentEntry
{
       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("x")]
       public String X;

       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("y")]
       public String Y;
}
```

generic/xml.cs

```
public class xml : ContentEntry
{
      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("path")]
      public String Path;
}
```

xml/add.cs

```
public class add : ContentEntry
{
      [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("z")]
      public String Z;
}
```

Is there anyway I can archive this ? Or do I have to implement some sort of logic into the XmlSerializer ?

Best Regards,

Comment: try this link to convert XML to CS http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ and serialize / deserialize objects

Comment: You can use the standard serialize functions.  Just change the names of the two add classes so they are different.  Then use [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("add")] and  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("add")] so the serialize function now that actual tag name.  The XmlRoot can go above any class, not just the Root tag in the xml